# SharePoint 2013 List of Features and Hardware Requirements?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

Does anyone here have the answer to the following SharePoint 2013 related questions?

1. Hardware Requirements
2. Official List of Features and Enhancements
3. Official Beta Release Date
4. Targeted Microsoft .NET Framework for SharePoint 2013

Any information on any of the above will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Pete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 system requirements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485%28office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: So I keep hearing. Where is the blessed page? :)

Comment: I think they are still putting the documentation together. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/evalcenter/hh973397

Comment: Yep, it looks like they just posted the requirements. Minimum Requirements for Developer is 4 GB RAM, 64-bit, four core processor for small deployments and 80 GB of storage. Production 8 GB RAM for production use in a single server or multiple server farm, 64-bit, eight core processor for medium deployments. 

It looks like I will have to upgrade yet again! This stinks!

Pete

Comment: Minimum for dev is RAM: 8GB (Foundation) or 24GB (Server), 4 cores and 80Gb disk (F and S). Be carefull what you read on technet. Some information is still for 2010, be sure to check if the information on the page is really for 2013 (don't trust the link titles!)

Answer (score 2):

If they did its not going to be posted here. Everyone is under an NDA on this type of information.

If I had to take a stab at guessing a beta release I would say October-November. Its usually right around the time of the SharePoint Conference. When 2010 beta was released it was November about a month after the conference. I have heard talks that GA would be around Spring. I do believe they are looking to release all of the Wave 15 product at about the same time.

Hardware requirements will probably be very close to what 2010 was.

Comment: Thanks Cory. Are you guessing about Hardware requirements or is this based on any type of research or source?

Comment: I would call it an educated guess. I cant see Microsoft changing the minimum hardware requirements drastically. Keep in  mind that it is always going to depend on requirements of the environment anyway.

Comment: I disagree. Microsoft quadrupled the HW requirements from 2007 to 2010, so expect SP2013 to be heavy on the HW requirements. Worst case, you have a better performing server.

Comment: Not saying that it isnt going to go up. I just dont feel that it is going to be as drastic as the increase from 2007 to 2010. Best thing to do is to give it as much as you can. I still have heated discussions from time to time with people who only want to give me 4GB for 2010. It works but the performance isnt good. In the documentation I always leave it hightlighted in RED/BOLD that the server does not meet recommended minimums.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning release dates - There has been leaked roadmap of Office 15 (also know as Office 2013). See [this article](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-roadmap-leaks-for-office-15-ie-10-and-more-key-products/12417). I recommend following [the blog of Mary-Jo Foley](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft) for news about new Microsoft products.

Comment: Anything Mary-Jo has posted about Office or SharePoint 15 is speculation not news. Nothing has been announced by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

DigiOz,

I've been doing extensive research into what's known and rumored around SP2013. To answer your questions in order:

1. Nobody knows about hardware requirements.
2. I've posted a list of features from the protocol documentation here: http://blog.furuknap.net/sharepoint-server-2013-features
3. Although not official, a beta of both Office 15 and SharePoint 15 (codenamed as such) is expected in early June along with or around the time of the Release Preview of Windows 8.
4. SharePoint 2013 will be based on .NET 4.0 runtime.

Oh, and nothing of this is 'official'. It's purely speculation at this point, so treat it as such.

.b

Comment: Thank you Bjørn this is very helpful, although I realize it is probably not final. Now if we could just get the hardware specs we would be in good shape.

Answer (score 1):

1.Hardware Requirements

- IT: http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc262485(v=office.15)

2.Official List of Features and Enhancements

- IT: http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc261970(v=office.15)

3.Official Beta Release Date - 7/16

4.Targeted Microsoft .NET Framework for SharePoint 2013 - 4.5 RC

Answer (score 1):

Here are some good FAQ about SPS 2013. I love the new version.

http://ekhichdi.com/a/Common-Questions-on-Sharepoint-2013-468.html

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the same thing and found this tool so thought id reply here, for those who want an add-in to easily display related content, as well as auto set and hide the parent item lookup column from children item forms
https://store.qipoint.com/SharePoint-Related-List-Content-Viewer-p/sp14-00-rlist.htm
Hope that helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of more pragmatic features. A new app store is the most likely feature to help tie in all those third-party products to help users create and buy packaged solutions. An educational module has been widely touted to help it access the huge learning sector. More:

http://blog.furuknap.net/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-features-loops 
and 
http://blog.furuknap.net/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-features-state-machines

Answer (score 0):

Here is a url to page which has couple of good links about Sharepoint 2013

http://digitalmacgyver.wordpress.com/2012/07/16/sharepoint-2013-beta-customer-previewlinks-you-need/

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this link... http://bharathtechupdate.blogspot.com/2012/07/sharepoint-2013-technical-preview.html

I have some links in that blog post that contains consolidate links to some Training Kit videos and so many other articles related to SharePoint 2013.